# Round Datetime Object DOWN in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to round a `datetime` object DOWN in Python, and am having a few problems. There is lots on here about rounding `datetime` but I can't find anything specific to my needs.

I'm trying to get a date range of 15 minute intervals, with `.now()` being the end point. To get my `end=` I do:

`pd.Timestamp.now().round('15min')`

which returns:

`2019-08-16 11:15:00` which is exactly what I want, however, if I run this at 11:23 say, it will return me `2019-08-16 11:30:00`, and that's not actually what I want, I want it to round down to `2019-08-16 11:15:00` up until the moment we strike 11:30.

Is there a simple way to get it to round down as I haven't had any luck finding the answer if so.

Cheers for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Timestamp.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html):

```
print (pd.Timestamp('2019-08-16 11:15:00').floor('15min'))
2019-08-16 11:15:00
print (pd.Timestamp('2019-08-16 11:23:00').floor('15min'))
2019-08-16 11:15:00
print (pd.Timestamp('2019-08-16 11:30:00').floor('15min'))
2019-08-16 11:30:00
```

For testing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':pd.date_range('2009-01-01', freq='T', periods=20)})

df['new'] = df['dates'].dt.floor('15min')
print (df)

0  2009-01-01 00:00:00 2009-01-01 00:00:00
1  2009-01-01 00:01:00 2009-01-01 00:00:00
2  2009-01-01 00:02:00 2009-01-01 00:00:00
3  2009-01-01 00:03:00 2009-01-01 00:00:00
4  2009-01-01 00:04:00 2009-01-01 00:00:00
5  2009-01-01 00:05:00 2009-01-01 00:00:00
6  2009-01-01 00:06:00 2009-01-01 00:00:00
7  2009-01-01 00:07:00 2009-01-01 00:00:00
8  2009-01-01 00:08:00 2009-01-01 00:00:00
9  2009-01-01 00:09:00 2009-01-01 00:00:00
10 2009-01-01 00:10:00 2009-01-01 00:00:00
11 2009-01-01 00:11:00 2009-01-01 00:00:00
12 2009-01-01 00:12:00 2009-01-01 00:00:00
13 2009-01-01 00:13:00 2009-01-01 00:00:00
14 2009-01-01 00:14:00 2009-01-01 00:00:00
15 2009-01-01 00:15:00 2009-01-01 00:15:00
16 2009-01-01 00:16:00 2009-01-01 00:15:00
17 2009-01-01 00:17:00 2009-01-01 00:15:00
18 2009-01-01 00:18:00 2009-01-01 00:15:00
19 2009-01-01 00:19:00 2009-01-01 00:15:00
```